# Matching plot line colour with the name of the division

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot mean of 'Sales' for 7 divisions (blue, green, grey, orange, purple, red, yellow) for each response month. Here is a code snippet:

```
subset_sales = (df_2.pivot_table(index=['Response Month (YYYY-MM)'],
                                 columns='Division', values='Sales')
                .reset_index()
                .set_index('Response Month (YYYY-MM)')
                )
subset_sales.plot(kind='line', rot=90)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIUA0.png)

How can I ensure that colour of plot line for each division matches the name of the division i.e. 'blue' colour plotline for blue division, 'yellow' colour plotline for yellow division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `style` to assign line color. The expectation is that you pass a dictionary of column and color pairs to style. As your column names are the color you want to assign to each line, you need to have each entry as `'Blue':'Blue'` and so on. So, you can update your plot as below...

```
subset_sales.plot(kind='line', rot=90, style={c: i for i, c in zip(subset_sales.columns, subset_sales.columns)})
```

and you will get the below plot.

[image]